# How to detect packet sniffers?

Tags: command-line, networking, internet, packet-analyzer

If found, what should one do? What packages or commands should I run to find packet sniffers and what should I do next to defend and protect yourself from it?

Answer (score 2):

Packet sniffers come in different form. Some packet sniffers used by network admin to detect misconfiguration and troubleshooting the network and others are hackers used to sniff on the network for collecting passwords, users critical data etc. Hackers can use sniffers to eavesdrop on unencrypted data in the packets to see what information is being exchanged between two parties. They can also capture information such as passwords and authentication tokens (if they are sent in the clear).

To protect yourself from hackers, it is strongly recommended:

- Always protect your traffic with SSL or TLS which will help you to protect your network traffic from being sniffed. Note: Hackers can sniff traffic but they will see some gibberish data because the data is encrypted.
- If you are a network admin and want to know if someone is using a sniffing tool. It can be detected using "[antisniff tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581924/anti-sniff-or-sniff-detection)" such as sniffdet, sniffer.detectors, ntop etc.